# 'grep' does not work with 'time'?

Tags: grep, time

Why does `time ls | grep real` output this

```
real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

instead of just

```
real    0m0.002s
```

If I type

```
echo -e 'real\t0m0.002s\nuser\t0m0.000s\nsys\t0m0.002s\n' | grep real
```

I get what I expect, i.e.

```
real    0m0.002s
```

I found that this works

```
(time ls)  2>&1 > /dev/null | grep real
```

What does this command do?

Comment: Because `time` is calculating the elapsed time for `ls | grep real` not for `ls`?

Comment: woah!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Writing answer.

Comment: actually `a=$(time ls); echo $a|grep real` leads to the same problem

Comment: See my updated answer which explains why it didn't work and how your new command gets around the problem.

Comment: It is preferable to use `{ time ls; }` instead of `( time ls )`, as the latter launches a subshell, whereas the former runs in the current shell. In fact the whole expression can be simplified to `{ time ls; } |& grep real`, which merges `stderr` into `stdout` for the whole command, including the `time` output, and `grep` can then extract the data you want. This is a slightly more complex form of your original expression, with the two elaborations of grouping the `time ls` command and merging `stderr` into `stdout`.

Answer (score 6):

#### Why does `time ls | grep real` not work as expected.

`time` is a `bash` reserved word and behaves differently than `/usr/bin/time`.

> If the time reserved word precedes a pipeline, the elapsed as well as user and system time consumed by its execution are reported **when the pipeline terminates**.

Source [bash(1): GNU Bourne-Again SHell - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

In addition, `time` outputs to standard error not standard output.

Use the following command:

```
(time ls) 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep real
```

Notes:

- The `(` and `)` groups the `time` and `ls` commands together (so these commands get evaluated first)
- `2>&1 >/dev/null` first redirects stderr to stdout (which is the pipe) and then redirects stdout to `/dev/null`.

  So stderr goes to the pipe and stdout goes nowhere.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [brackets](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-brackets.html) - Using parenthesis to group and expand expressions.
- [syntax-redirection](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection and Process Substitution.
- [Bash Reference Manual: Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)
- [Illustrated Redirection Tutorial [Bash Hackers Wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial)

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, it works, but it require a bit of I/O redirection :)

```
$ exec 3>&1 4>&2
{ time sleep 1 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1 |
    grep 'real'    
exec 3>&- 4>&-
```

### Output :

```
real    0m1,003s
```

Read [bash FAQ#32](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032) and [I/O redirection tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial)

---

### A quite simpler way :

```
$ TIMEFORMAT=%R
$ time sleep 1
1,003
```

Comment: is this arab language?

Comment: This is bash I/O redirection ^^

Comment: can you explain me what is going on?

Comment: Check the linked page

Comment: lol. that is overkill for the OPs problem :)

Comment: Added simplest method

Answer (score 2):

Two issues here.

First and most important, "time" send it's output to stderr (standard error) not stdout, so that it will not be captured by normal redirection commands unless you take special measures.

Second, time is not a normal program but a special built-in command interpreted directly by the shell (for shells like bash, csh, tcsh, etc,).  It thus works in a non-standard way and it times the whole rest of the command-line (unless you are using a very unusual shell).

So, to get the result you want (using bash), you need to use:

```
(time ls) 2>&1 | grep real
```

This will run the "ls" in a subshell and time it [ **(time ls)** ] , send standard error to standard out **[ 2>&1 ]** , and then send standard out to "grep" [ **|grep** ].

The last part that you used ">?dev/null" throws away the normal output from the ls command itself, in case that included the word "real."

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `time` writes direct to the console and not to `stdout`, which means that the output from the command or pipeline is not affected by adding `time`.

So `grep` never sees the time report, which in any case is generated after `grep` completes, since the whole pipeline is timed.